# How to save an excel as part of windows form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have a piece of code which reads from an excel template which goes like this,

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\WebcamExcel\Webcam1.xlsx"))
{
  //Do My stuff
}
```

Currently I have pasted it in the given path, however how can I add this as part of my Windows Form application installation?

Also if the user installed in a different disk rather than C drive, how better can I write the above code to check it from installed location?

Comment: Do you want to read the file from the same directory the application is installed? You can get the path using Application.StartupPath

Comment: Thanks @vgSefa. I added the excel file to my winform application, however it is not found in installed folders. Should I be adding this in some app folder or something?

Comment: in VS click on file and open properties. Change "copy to output folder" option to "copy if never"

Comment: Thanks lot can you please add this as the answer? I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\Webcam1.xlsx"))
{
  //Do My stuff
}
```